# Error: Exception in HostFunction: Attempting to create an object of type 'sets' with an existing primary key value '6' in react native

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm trying to store history of workout in realm, my **addHistory** function looks like this

```
export function addHistory(workout, exercise, sets, _id) {
  console.log({
    workout,
    exercise,
    sets,
    _id,
  });
  if (
    _id !== undefined &&
    workout !== undefined &&
    exercise !== undefined &&
    sets !== undefined
  ) {
    // return console.log("HISTORY ", { workout, exercise, sets, _id });

    return realm.write(() => {
      return realm.create("workoutData", {
        _id: _id,
        exercise,
        workout,
        sets,
        workoutDate: new Date(Date.now()),
      });
    });
  } else {
    alert("History is incomplete");
  }
}
```

Schema of the workoutData is as follows:

```
exports.workoutData = {
  name: "workoutData",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
    _id: "int",
    workout: "workouts",
    exercise: "exercise",
    workoutDate: "date",
    sets: "sets[]",
  },
};
```

Now when I add sets and click on **finishWorkoutHandler** the logic works fine before the **addHistory** function but when **addHistory** is executed it throws the error as stated in the question.

```
//finish workout handler
  const finishWorkoutHandler = () => {
    if (sets.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    let setsFromRealm = realm.objects("sets");

    let workoutData = realm.objects("workoutData");

    let setsArray = [];

    exercises.forEach((exercise) => {
      sets
        .filter((items) => items.exercise._id == exercise._id)
        .forEach((sets) => {
          let _id = 0;
          if (setsFromRealm.length > 0) {
            _id = realm.objects("sets").max("_id") + 1;
          }

          addSet(
            sets.name,
            parseInt(sets.weight),
            parseInt(sets.reps),
            parseInt(sets.rmValue),
            sets.isHeighest,
            sets.exercise,
            _id,
            sets.profile,
            sets.failedSet,
            sets.warmupSet,
            sets.notes
          );

          let indiSet = {
            name: sets.name,
            weight: parseInt(sets.weight),
            reps: parseInt(sets.reps),
            rmValue: parseInt(sets.rmValue),
            isHeighest: sets.isHeighest,
            _id: _id,
            profile: sets.profile,
            failedSet: sets.failedSet,
            warmupSet: sets.warmupSet,
            notes: sets.notes,
            createdDate: new Date(Date.now()),
          };

          setsArray.push(indiSet);
        });

      let workoutDataId = 0;
      let setsArrcopy = setsArray;

      console.log("SETS ", realm.objects("sets"));
      console.log("SETS ", setsArrcopy);

      if (workoutData.length > 0) {
        workoutDataId = realm.objects("workoutData").max("_id") + 1;
      }

      **WORKING AS EXPECTED TILL HERE**

      // problem lies here
      addHistory(params.workout, exercise, setsArrcopy, workoutDataId);
    });
    dispatch(setsEx([]));
    goBack();
  };
```

the structure of **setsArrCopy** containing sets is as follows

```
         [
          ({
            _id: 6,
            createdDate: 2022-09-29T16:27:06.128Z,
            failedSet: false,
            isHeighest: false,
            name: "Thai",
            notes: "",
            profile: [Object],
            reps: 12,
            rmValue: 64,
            warmupSet: false,
            weight: 56,
          },
          {
            _id: 7,
            createdDate: 2022-09-29T16:27:06.151Z,
            failedSet: false,
            isHeighest: false,
            name: "Thsi 3",
            notes: "",
            profile: [Object],
            reps: 10,
            rmValue: 75,
            warmupSet: false,
            weight: 66,
          })
        ];
```

the logic is also working fine in terms of assigning new ids to the sets being added in a loop. But somehow its throwing error when passing **setArrCopy** to **addHistory** function. Although its an array of sets not a single object?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is either use the default uuid property type provided by realm within you scheme config or ensure that the _id value you are passing with each object is unique.

You can use uuidv4 or v5 library for that too.